# error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Robot'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11

**QUESTION** (answer below the question)

I know there's lot of questions like mine, but I didn't find the solution for my problem anyway.

I'w writing small project for school and everything was running with no problem until I added: `#include "robot.h"` into **interface.h** and added `, Robot* _robot` in **init** function in **interface.h**.

I'm writing it with Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate *(I'm a student ;) )*. The whole code is accessible on [github](https://github.com/Xkonti/RoboSim) and those are files written by me:

- allegroHelper.h .cpp - some functions for ease of use allegro library
- interface.h .cpp - class for drawing interface
- logic.h .cpp - logic of the robot
- robot.h .cpp - robot class
- libs/xkontiTextUtils.h .cpp - some fancy console functions (some are broken)
- libs/xkontiVector2d.h .cpp - little vector class

The thing that is breaking my code is there:

```
//interface.h
#pragma once


//////////////////////////////////////////
// INCLUDES
//////////////////////////////////////////

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "libs/xkontiTextUtils.h"
#include "libs/xkontiVector2d.h"
#include <allegro5/allegro.h>
#include "allegro5/allegro_image.h"
#include <allegro5/allegro_primitives.h>
#include "robot.h"
//#include "allegroHelper.h"    // Not needed due to forward declatation?


//////////////////////////////////////////
// INTERFACE CLASS
//////////////////////////////////////////

class Interface {
public:
    Interface();
    ~Interface();

    bool init(std::string _mapPath, int _width, XkontiConsoleColors* _con, Robot* _robot);
    (...)
    Robot* robot;
    (...)
};
```

Robot class is in **robot.h**:

```
//robot.h
#pragma once


//////////////////////////////////////////
// INCLUDES
//////////////////////////////////////////

#include <iostream>

#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
#include "libs/xkontiTextUtils.h"
#include "libs/xkontiVector2d.h"

#include <allegro5/allegro.h>
#include "allegro5/allegro_image.h"
#include <allegro5/allegro_primitives.h>

#include "allegroHelper.h"


//////////////////////////////////////////
// ROBOT CLASS
//////////////////////////////////////////

class Robot {
public:
    // Constuctor & Destructor
    Robot(std::vector< std::vector<bool> >& _map);
    ~Robot();

    // Initialization functions
    void initBody(Vector2D _size, Vector2D _pos, double _rotation, double _maxVelocity, double _maxAVelocity);
    void initHead(Vector2D _pos, Vector2D _rotRange, double _rangeMin, double _rangeMax, double _rangeError, unsigned int _resolution, double _rangeLess, double _rangeOver);

    // Set Functions
    void setPos(Vector2D _newPos);
    void setPos(double _x, double _y);
    void setRotation(double _rad);

    // Get Functions
    Vector2D getPos();
    Vector2D getHeadPos();
    double getRotation();
    int getStatus();

    // Commands Functions
    void move(double _dist);                // Move robot forward by specified distance
    void move(double _dist, double _rad);   // Move and turn robot
    void turn(double _rad);             // Turn robot by specified degree value
    std::vector<double>& scan();        // Scans terrain. Returns reference to vector of distances.

    // Periodical Functions
    void update(double dt);
    void draw(double dt);

    // Public Variables
    std::vector<Vector2D> scanPoints;

private:
    // Body functions

    // Head functions
    double trace(double _rad);          // Measure distance from current position

    // Outside pointers
    std::vector< std::vector<bool> >& map;

    // Body properties
    Vector2D size;      // Dimensions: Width, Length
    Vector2D pos;           // Position: X, Y
    double rotation;                    // Rotation: Z axis
    double leftDistance;                // Distance left to travel
    double leftRotation;                // Rotation left to rotate
    double maxVelocity;             // Max forward velocity
    double maxAVelocity;                // Max angular velocity on Z axis (left/right)

    // Head properties
    Vector2D headPos;           // Head position: X, Y
    Vector2D headRotRange;  // Head Z rotation range: from - to in deg
    double rangeMin;            // Minimum and Maximum detection range
    double rangeMax;
    double rangeError;          // Error percentage on range measuring
    unsigned int resolution;    // Number of traces in left/right scan
    double rangeLess;           // Number used when something was nearer than rangeMin
    double rangeOver;           // Number used when nothing was detected
};
```

The error I'm getting from compiler:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: RoboSim, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  robot.cpp
1>d:\xkonti\github\robosim\interface.h(28): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Robot'
1>d:\xkonti\github\robosim\interface.h(39): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>d:\xkonti\github\robosim\interface.h(39): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>  logic.cpp
1>d:\xkonti\github\robosim\interface.h(28): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Robot'
1>d:\xkonti\github\robosim\interface.h(39): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>d:\xkonti\github\robosim\interface.h(39): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>  xkontiVector2d.cpp
1>  Generating Code...
1>  Skipping... (no relevant changes detected)
1>  interface.cpp
1>  allegroHelper.cpp
1>  RoboSim.cpp
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I looked for circular dependencies with `#include` but:

1. I use `#pragma once` in every header
2. I found that I include **interface.h** in **allegroHelper.h** and **allegroHelper.h** in **interface.h** and it was compiling without problem for long time.

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong? Or any hints what to check?

**ANSWER**

Ok. I dont have much time and because I didn't find any way to have pointer to Robot class in Interface, I'm accessing data by references to some data in Robot class.

In main file:

```
//RoboSim.cpp
std::vector< std::vector<bool> > map;
std::vector<Vector2D> scanPoints;
ALLEGRO_BITMAP* image = nullptr;
(...)
Interface inter = Interface(scanPoints);
Robot robot = Robot(map, scanPoints);
(...)
```

In Interface class:

```
//interface.h
(...)
class Interface {
public:
    Interface(std::vector<Vector2D>& _scanPoints);
    ~Interface();
    (...)
private:
    XkontiConsoleColors* con;
    std::vector<Vector2D>& scanPoints;
    (...)
```

In Robot class:

```
//robot.h
(...)
class Robot {
public:
    // Constuctor & Destructor
    Robot(std::vector< std::vector<bool> >& _map, std::vector<Vector2D>& scanPoints);
    ~Robot();
    (...)
    std::vector< std::vector<bool> >& map;
    std::vector<Vector2D>& scanPoints;
    (...)
```

Comment: Compiler is telling you that it does not know what a `Robot` is. Where is `Robot` defined?

Comment: I've never used #pragma once, but instead created an #ifndef, #define, #endif around the .h, each one getting a different name.  Post your robot.h

Comment: Just added robot.h to the post. This is not semicolon @πάντα ῥεῖ

Answer (score 2):

I had to dig into your project to see the problem. You are including interface.h in robot.h through allegroHelper.h, and therefore `Robot` is not defined the first time you see its use.

Instead of using `#include`, you can forward-declare a lot of what you're doing.

```
#pragma once


//////////////////////////////////////////
// INCLUDES
//////////////////////////////////////////

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "libs/xkontiTextUtils.h"
#include "libs/xkontiVector2d.h"
#include <allegro5/allegro.h>
#include "allegro5/allegro_image.h"
#include <allegro5/allegro_primitives.h>
// #include "robot.h"
#include "allegroHelper.h"

// the definition of Robot is not actually used, so just its name needs to be known here
class Robot;


//////////////////////////////////////////
// INTERFACE CLASS
//////////////////////////////////////////

class Interface {...};
```

Comment: You should always repeat this pattern as much as possible. Before including a header file, ask yourself "do I need the *definition*, or just the *declaration*?"

Comment: I tried commenting out `#include "robot.h"` and it does'n work. I checked dependencies and there are no *double includes* of **robot.h**. I can only comment out `#include "allegroHelper.h"` and it won't change error output.

Comment: And i need *definition* of **Robot** in **interface.cpp** in **init**: [link](https://github.com/Xkonti/RoboSim/blob/master/interface.cpp)

Comment: Your include chain goes like this: robot.h->allegroHelper.h->interface.h->robot.h. Since `Robot` still hasn't been defined in the first parse of robot.h, and the second parse will be skipped because of the `#pragma once`, `Robot` is unknown inside of interface.h

Comment: Your .cpp files should include whatever they need, but you should strive to `#include` as *few* .h files in your own .h files --preferably none.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this @moswald. You've been helpful and I'll remember this for future ;)